# Join multiple one to many related tables in EF and select as view model

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2008, join

Database Models of my Application are:

```
public class Restaurant 
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   .........
} 

public class Review
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ReviewTitle { get; set; }
    public string ReviewContent { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int RestaurantId { get; set; }
}

public ReviewHelpful
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ReviewId { get; set; }
    public bool IsHelpfull { get; set; }
}

public ReviewImage
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string ImageLink { get; set; }
   public int ReviewId { get; set; }
}
```

There is no navigation property in any table. In `ReviewHelpful` table, If user finds helpfull of this review than value is `true` otherwise `false`.
Now I want to create a view-model Like this:

```
public class ReviewViewModel 
{
       public int ReviewId { get; set; }
       public int RestaurantId { get; set; }
       public string ReviewTitle { get; set; }
       public string ReviewContent { get; set; }
       public int UserId { get; set; }
       public int NumberOfHelpfull { get; set; }
       public int NumberOfNotHelpfull { get; set; }
       public List<string> ImagesLinks { get; set; }
}
```

For that reason, I want to write this kind of query :

```
var reviews = (from review in _foodTrackerContext.RestaurantReviews
            join helpful in _foodTrackerContext.Helpfuls on review.Id equals helpful.ReviewId
            join reviewPicture in _foodTrackerContext.ReviewPictures on review.Id equals reviewPicture.ReviewId
            where review.ResturantId == 2
            select new ReviewViewModel()
            {
                Id = review.Id,
                RestaurantId = 2,
                ReviewTitle = review.ReviewTitle,
                ReviewContent = review.ReviewContent,
                NumberOfHelpfull = .. ??,
                NumberOfNotHelpfull = ... ??, 
                ImagesLinks = ... ???
            }
```

I can not retrieve `HelpfulYes`, `HelpfulNo`, `ImagesLinks` with this query. What would be query for finding these variables?.

This query produces multiple rows for single review with each `ReviewImage` and each `ReviewHelpful`.

Comment: And what is the problem? What is not working?

Comment: Can't retrive `HelpfulYes`, `HelpfulNo` and `ImagesLinks`.

Comment: Please, review your question again. For example, add the missing `class` keywords. And make it consistent: first you show this: `public class ReviewViewModel ` and then you use it like this: `select new RestaurantReviewViewModel()` with a different name.

Answer (score 1):

The query that ypu need to do is this one:

```
var model = 
    from review in ctx.Reviews
    where review.RestaurantId == 2
    join helpful in ctx.ReviewHelpfuls
        on review.Id equals helpful.ReviewId into helpfuls
    join image in ctx.ReviewImages
        on review.Id equals image.ReviewId into images
    select new RestaurantReviewViewModel
    {
        Id = review.Id,
        RestaurantId = 2,
        ReviewTitle = review.ReviewTitle,
        ReviewContent = review.ReviewContent,
        NumberOfHelpfull = helpfuls.Count(h => h.IsHelpfull),
        NumberOfNotHelpfull = helpfuls.Count(h => !h.IsHelpfull),
        ImagesLinks = (from image in images select image.ImageLink).ToList()
    };
```

Please, note that when you do a one to manyh join you need to  include an `into` to give a nameto the joined entities to be able to work on them.

I've used the dot syntax for selecting the count, but you could use the query syntax if you wanted. Over time, I've found dot synatx more natural.

NOTE: if you used navigation properties this would become much easier. Why are you not using them? With navigation properties you don't need to make the joins explicitly, as they are already available.

Comment: Problem is, this query produce multiple rows for each imageLink and helpful for single review. I can not produce count of `NumberOfHelpful`, `NumberOfNotHelpful` and `ImageLinks` .

Comment: `ImagesLinks = (from image in images select image.ImageLink).ToList()`  this line returns me `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.String] ToList[String](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable 1[System.String]) method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.` this error.

Comment: I don't know what you're doing in a different way, but I have a proof of concept owith exactly this code working. The kind of error you're showing make no sense in a place where you're materializing the query. You must have written something different.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<ReviewViewModel> listModel = new List<ReviewViewModel>();


                 context.dbRestaurant
                                   .include("Review")
                                   .include("Review.ReviewHelpful")
                                   .include("Review.ReviewImage").ToList().ForEach((item) =>
            {
               ReviewViewModel model = new ReviewViewModel();
                  model.ID = item.ID
                listModel.Add(model);
            });
```